# Fatal Exception Error main

Tags: java, json

Getting Fatal Exception. I want response from server through php api. But everytime I get this error

```
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): Process: com.example.googlemap, PID: 1314
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.vss.lcm.gps.JSONPARSER1.makeHttpRequest(JSONPARSER1.java:64)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.vss.lcm.gps.Supervisornew$GetContacts$1.run(Supervisornew.java:97)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-01 07:16:35.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is

```
package com.vss.lcm.gps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.googlemap.MainActivity2;
import com.example.googlemap.R;

public class Supervisornew extends Activity {

    Button bt;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String id = "9999999999";

    private static String url_detail = "http://dyandroidapps.netii.net/gettinglatlngdynamically.php";
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    // private static String url =
    // "http://dyandroidapps.netii.net/android_db/newdymodifiedserver.php";
    // JSON parser class
    JSONPARSER1 jsonParser = new JSONPARSER1();

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "product";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String TAG_LNG = "lng";

    // contacts JSONArray
    // JSONArray contacts = null;
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.supervisor);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_supervisor);
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    }

    public void track(View v) {
        // new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        new GetContacts().execute();
        // new RetrieveTask().execute();
    }

    // private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, ArrayList<String>,
    // Void>
    class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Supervisornew.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_detail, "GET", params);
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject contacts = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                            String lng = c.getString(TAG_LNG);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "lat" + lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "lng" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Log.d("response", lat);
                            Log.d("response", lng);// here i m getting values in
                                                    // log

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("lat", lat);
                            map.put("lng", lng);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lng,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            contactList.add(map);
                        }

                        if (contactList != null) {
                            Intent intentmap = new Intent(Supervisornew.this,
                                    MainActivity2.class);
                            intentmap.putExtra("arraylist", contactList);
                            startActivityForResult(intentmap, 500);
                        }

                        else {
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
}
```

My JsonParser file is

```
public class JSONPARSER1 {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONPARSER1() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

I can't understand why I'm getting this error. Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: are you working on android application?

Comment: @DEEPAKYADAV sorry Here the correct link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: I cant understand the flow of code here@Jens